# jQuery Copy text field's value from a different form into another form's text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two forms.

I want to copy the value of one of the text fields in form 1 into another in form 2.

Text field names and ids are different.

How can I achieve this?

This didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('name').value = document.getElementById('user').value;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery or not - because thats vanilla js youve posted in your question?

Comment: Check for duplicate ID, that is invalid and would have the potential to make the above fail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're asking for jQuery you could try:

```
$("#name").val($("#user").val());
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbin.com/exudif/2/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#btn1').click(function()
    {
         $('#field2').val($('#field1').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value using jquery .it has to be done this way . 
Also make sure you have given id to the input fields .

like this: `<input type='text' name='user' id='user' >`

Then only this code will work properly

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#buttonElement').click(function()
    {
         $('#name').val($('#user').val());
    });
});
```